# Calculus with Mathematica, books, interesting examples

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, reference-request

I'm looking for a book where I could find informations and interesting examples regarding examine functions of one variable like continuity of functions, limits, differentiability in Mathematica. I'd like to find examples, which sometimes is hard to compute on paper, but Mathematica helps us, which show unusual features.

I just start my adventure with Mathematica, so I ask for recommendation of books, sites, or if someone has an idea- just show a few examples.
I'll be very grateful, because I need  a foothold. Thank you

Edit:
I'd like to focus on examples, which show interesting features of functions, like Weierstrass function is continuous but not differientable. This could be example regarding dependecy continuity and differentiability or limit and continuity. Something what is especially easier and worth to prove in Mathematica.

Comment: Like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice)

Comment: [Mathematica Navigator](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematica-Navigator-Mathematics-Statistics-Graphics/dp/0123741645) has some good examples.